# My trait function is not identified within the class

Tags: laravel, function, traits

here is my code 
This is the code that I wrote in Trait and I defined the function categories.

```
namespace App\Traits;
use App\Models\Category;
trait Categorizable
{
     public function categories()
     {
         return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'Categorize');
     }
}
```

and in controller
And use this function inside the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'vahed_id' => 'required',
        'min_limit' => 'required',
        'max_limit' => 'required',
    ], [
        'name.required' => 'افزودن نام کالا اجباری می باشد',
        'vahed_id.required' => 'افزودن واحد اجباری می باشد',
        'min_limit.required' => 'افزودن حد کمبود اجباری می باشد',
        'max_limit.required' => 'افزودن حد کالای اضافه اجباری می باشد',
    ]);
    $new_product_data = Product::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'vahed_id' => $request->input('vahed_id'),
        'min_limit' => $request->input('min_limit'),
        'max_limit' => $request->input('max_limit'),
        'comment' => $request->input('comment'),
        'barcode' => $request->input('barcode'),
        'view' => $request->input('view'),
    ]);
    if ($new_product_data){
        if ($request->has('categorize')){
            $new_product_data->categories()->sync($request->input('categorize'));
        }
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin_user.dashboard.pishniaz.product.product')->with('success', 'محصول جدید با موفقیت ایجاد گردید.');

}
```

this is my error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laranbar.categorizes' doesn't exist (SQL: select `category_category_id` from `Categorizes` where `Categorize_id` = 18 and `Categorize_type` = App\Models\Product)

If I put it in this way:
    $new_product_data->$this->categories()->sync($request->input('categorize'));

this is my error:
Object of class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductsController could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1):

Add in your `App\Product` Model

```
use App\Traits\Categorizable;
class Product extends Model 
{
    use Categorizable;

}
```